# Python 3.6 : Sorting in Python vs Sorting in SQL

Tags: python, sql

I compared the order by of SQL and the built in function sorted() in python. I hoped that it gives me the same result but not.
Here is the portion of SQL:
`order by r.date, r.age_range, r.type_id asc;`
and it gives me this :

1
    2
    3
    4
    16
    5
    17
    6
    18
    7
    19
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15

(those are the Id i want).
In python i used this code:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda r: (r.date, r.age_range, r.type_id))
```

and it gives me this : 1 2 3 16 4 17 5 18 6 7 19 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

(Problem with the last criteria (r.type_id)). Can someone explain me and help me? Thank you.

Ps : data is list of object; date is string; age is integer; type is integer also. 
The result i want:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the actual values being sorted, there is nothing that anyone can do.

Comment: Yes. The result of `SELECT date, age, "type" FROM table_name ORDER BY date, age, "type" ASC` would be very useful.

Comment: Also, some explanation of "(the r.type parameter doesn't work)" might shed light. Do you mean that it doesn't appear to be being sorted correctly?

Comment: holdenweb : Yes, it's that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order by` in SQL is not stable.  That means that when the keys are all tied, the result can be in an arbitrary order -- and that order can even change from row to row.

You don't show the data, but it looks like you have ties among all three keys being used for some of the ids.  For instance:

- 4 and 16
- 5 and 17
- 6 and 18

You may have other ties as well; the arbitrary ordering in SQL happens to be the same as the ordering in Python.

`sorted` in Python *is* stable, so it preserves the original ordering of the row, when there are ties.

Why isn't sorting stable in SQL?  That is easy.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "original ordering" to fall back on.